# Asp.net, Silverlight and HTTPS - always validate certificate

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-4.0, ssl, certificate

I've a website that hosts the silverlight control. Silverlight control connects to the web service. It's SSL secured with the certificate. Now I want this certificate to be always validated successfully on my web page so the silverlight player can receive the streaming video. I do the following in Page_Load:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender1, cert, chain, error) => true;
```

However it doesn't work. It seems like the callback is not raised. 
Can someone please help me? Please note that I didn't add the certificate to the Trusted Root Authorieties on client side

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand how certificates work. If your server has a server-side certificate, then you validate it on the client. Consequently you can't validate it in the ASP.NET code. On the other hand, if you have a client-side certificate, then it makes no sense if you always trust it (and client-side certificates are not required in SSL).